# Why seekg does not work with getline?

Tags: c++, ifstream, getline, seekg

Seekg does not seem to work, when I reach EOF in myFile.

```
ifstream myFile("/path/file");
for(int i; i < 10; i++){
    myFile.seekg(0);//reset position in myFile
    while(getline(myFile, line)){
        doSomething
    }
}
```

So, now I am opening input stream every loop:

```
for(int i; i < 10; i++){
    ifstream myFile("/path/file");//reset position in myFile
    while(getline(myFile, line)){
        doSomething
    }
}
```

But I would rather seek to position 0. How can I achieve that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [seekg() function fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264764/seekg-function-fails)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make sure you clear the error flags before the call to `myFile.seekg()`:

```
myFile.clear();
```

After the EOF flag has ben set, you will not be able to extract anything. You have to clear those flags to be able to extract again.