# C++ Getline & seekg

Tags: c++

I have written a C++ program I have multiple of CSV file used as input, which I open one at a time and close it after extracting data to a output file which is the only file.

I run getline(inFile,line);
outFile << line << endl;

I run this code, only only few files it suddenly output after about 200-300 line after and have a big whitespace in my output CSV file

But when I slower the code, like system("Pause") in the loop, I can get extract what I want perfectly....

Is my program running to fast, why getline would be skipping part of what things I want?

I really have no idea where the problem is coming from, or where to start

Many Thanks!

```
if (dataname[i] == dataname)
{
    inFile.seekg(datalength[i], ios::beg);
    for (int j = 0; j < datacount[i]; j++)
    {
        getline(inFile, line);
        outFile << line << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: I think we need to see a bit more of your code. Where does `datalength[i]` come from, for example?

Comment: It is just the length for seekg...

Comment: And how did you get that "length"? My point is that, at least on Windows, the newlines are different length to `'\n'`, so seekg is not just the size of the data you have read.

Comment: Thanks Mat, let me explain how I did it, I got the length with, line.length();, I basically read the whole file and store the length in another CSV file. I have tested many random sample that it is correctly points to where I have calculated the length. The file format is like a security stock file just basic date,open,high,low,close. I just dont get why it would suddenly print out whitespace or "\n" if I run with too much multiple files to extract and put in one single file, but when system("pause"); it can do it perfectly....

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [Why seekg does not work with getline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15720586/why-seekg-does-not-work-with-getline?rq=1)

Add a clear() call before the seekg(pos) call to clear all error flags that might have been created by the getline(inFile, line) call.

```
inFile.clear();  // Clears all error flags.
inFile.seekg(pos);
```